# XmlRoot, XmlElement, InsertChildXml in PL/SQL function gives PLS-00201 identifier must be declared

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

> <sub>**Note:** Kindly do not flag this as a duplicate of a similar question. I am only asking this because the other questions do not address the exact same situtaion, and their answers do not provide a working solution.</sub>

If I use an XML related function like `INSERTCHILDXML` in a select statement like the following, it works completely fine:

```
SELECT INSERTCHILDXML( ... ) FROM DUAL;
```

But if I try to use this in PL/SQL as the following, it gives error `PLS-00201: identifier 'INSERTCHILDXML' must be declared`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ...
    RETURN XMLType
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN INSERTCHILDXML( ... );
EXCEPTION
    ...
END;
```

Functions having this problem: `XMLROOT`, `XMLELEMENT`, `INSERTCHILDXML`

There are scores of results when searching the web about the error. Many of them tell me to `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM` and `GRANT EXECUTE` on the problematic identifier. **But it doesn't work.**

Public synonym can be created for same name, but granting execute (on any schema) fails with:

```
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

If I try to use a different synonym name, upon trying to grant execute, I get:

```
ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid
```

How can I resolve the issue and **successfully use the listed functions** in my new PL/SQL function?

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>*After taking a short break (and looking at some more of similar questions), I reached an epiphany.*</sub>

Apparently the reason it did not work is because I was trying to `RETURN` the function output:

```sql
RETURN INSERTCHILDXML( ... );
```

What I should really be doing is push the output into a variable, then return the variable:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ...
    RETURN XMLType
AS
    temp XMLType;
BEGIN
    SELECT INSERTCHILDXML( ... ) INTO temp FROM DUAL;
    RETURN temp;
EXCEPTION
    ...
END;
```

**Note:** There is no need to create synonyms or grant execute permissions. If you have performed any of that, you can undo it.

**Additional findings:**

You cannot assign the function output to a variable. It must be pushed using `SELECT INTO`. You can however use the `XMLType` type and its methods.

```sql
temp := XMLType( ... ) -- works fine
temp := XMLELEMENT ( ... ) -- does not work
```

Usage in conditionals is flaky. `CASE WHEN` tolerates it while `IF` doesn't.

```sql
CASE WHEN EXISTSNODE( ... ) = 1 THEN -- works fine

IF EXISTSNODE( ... ) = 1 THEN -- does not work
```

You can circumvent the problem with `IF` by using a variable:

```sql
SELECT EXISTSNODE( ... ) INTO exists_node FROM DUAL;
IF exist_node = 1 THEN -- works
```